# Restart setInterval timer after keypress

Tags: jquery, arrays, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to loop through an array with index `i`.
What it currently increments `i` every 5 seconds.

However, I want to add in the option of manually incrementing `i`, which should reset the timer back to 5 seconds `(5000)`. How do I achieve this successfully?

So, for example,

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

On start, it should display (or whatever function I choose later) "a", wait 5 seconds, display "b"
If I press the right arrow key then it should immediately move to "c", but then wait 5 seconds again unless I press -> again.

I tried putting the increment in a separate function but this did not work so well.

```
    function doThis() {
if (i < (l + 1)) {
                        $('#myDiv').html(myArray[i]);

                        i++;
                        if (i == (l + 1)) {
                            doNext();
                        }
                    }}

                    var intervalHandle = setInterval(doThis, 5000); // start the interval by default
                    var running = true; // true if the interval is running, false if its not.




                            $("body").keydown(function (e) {
                                if (e.keyCode == 39) {//right

                                    console.log("testing");
                                    if (running) {
                                        clearInterval(intervalHandle); // stop interval
                                        running = false; // mark interval as stopped
                                    } else {
                                        intervalHandle = setInterval(doThis, 5000); // start interval
                                        running = true; // mark interval as started
                                        doThis(); // also change the image right now
                                    }


                                } else {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }

                            }); 

function doNext(){
//something here, when i ==l+1 as noted above 
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: If the user chooses to view something, stop the timer entirely. They may read slow and need more than five seconds, and they've obviously shown they know how to manually control it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to wrap your work in a closure where rather directly invoking setInterval you'll call a function that will call setInterval and then return a function that can be used to reset the interval and increment the passed in value.

```
function startInterval(i) {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
     i++
  }, 5000);

  return function() {
    clearInterval(interval)
    i++;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
     i++
    }, 5000);
  }
}

var i = 0;
var manualIncrement = startInterval(i);

$('body').keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 39) {
    manualIncrement();
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you @mkalish for the help! I'm a little confused still. 

Where would manualIncrement come into play?

Comment: @turner I've updated the example to show where the returned `manualIncrement` function would be called.

Comment: thank you again! I've updated my code above. 

I tried the one you wrote, but it didn't seem to work for me so I approached it another way, which still does not work. If you have any comments further it would be greatly appreciated.